# Constructive approach in proving the maximum modulus principle

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

In Brown and Churchill's book, the maximum modulus principle is stated as follows:

> If a function $f$ is analytic and not constant in a given domain
> $\Omega$, then $|f (z)|$ has no maximum value in $\Omega$.

In the proof, they stated the following. The question I have is as $d$ is a distance, wouldn't it always non-negative? How come it is only positive when it's the whole plane ?

[image]

> Draw a polygonal line $L$ lying in $\Omega$ and extending from $z_0$
> to any other point $P$ in $\Omega$. Let $d$ represent the shortest
> distance from points on $L$ to the boundary of $\Omega$. When $\Omega$
> is the entire plane, $d$ may have any positive value.

Comment: You’re misreading the text. When $\Omega$ is the whole plane, the boundary is the empty set, and they’re telling younto make $d$ a constant positive value. They did not say anything like what you said.